# How to focus on next edittext if there are a lot of them

Tags: android

I have several number of `EditText`'s in my layout if I have to go to next `EditText` I have to use `et1.addTextChangedListener` with following code inside it:

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    if (et1.getText().toString().length() == 1) {
        et2.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

I know that very well, but the problem is I have from 17 up to 20 `EditText`'s If I keep writing the code for every `EditText` my code will be the worst code of for the next 10 decades. How to handle this problem?

My case is very specific: when user presses a key on keyboard he need to focus on next `EditText` only. No `ACTION_UP` or `ACTION_DOWN`.

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence "No ACTION_UP or ACTION_DOWN."

Comment: Also, could you please specify the way you creating your EditTexts? Have you put them in xml manually, or they are dynamically created in java code?

Comment: I see, that you requirement is that every EditText is just one symbol. You shouldn't create 20 of them, just use customized one like this: https://github.com/glomadrian/material-code-input

Comment: @DimaRostopira means not enter key or any other forward keys

Comment: @DimaRostopira It's copy right one how can I use it for real time.

Comment: Where did you saw copyright? It's free open source library, just add it to your `build.gradle` and you are ready to go

Answer (score 0):

create a function that gets the first and second edittexts and check

```
    public void goToAnotherEditext(final EditText et1, final EditText et2){
    et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            if(et1.getText().toString().trim().length()==1){
                et2.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

then put the edittexts inside the function

```
 EditText et1 = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
    EditText et2 = new EditText(getApplicationContext());

    goToAnotherEditext(et1,et2);
```

Comment: Do you want me to write all the focus `up`,`down`,`right` in every `EditText`. I tried using single for every `EditText` not working.

Comment: nooo...pretend you have editext 1 called ETName and edittext2 called ETNumber. 
ETNumber is below the ETName and you want to go when you click next on keyboard to go from the ETName to ETNumber...

then inside the ETName you put android:nextFocusDown="@+id/ETNumber"

i am showing you all the codes that you want to use in each case of yours

hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

In your XML file, what you can do is make your edittext,

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

and you can then add imeOptions to change your current focus to next edittext,

```
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```

> imeOptions are used to navigate to next action item focusable. to know in deep use other attribute values of imeOptions.

In this way, you don't need to make your hands dirty by performing programmatical part. you can easily do this by XML Part.

Comment: I want focus to next `EditText` automatically. not with next arrow button

Comment: if a user enters only one character you want it to go to another edittext? please do elaborate more

Comment: @R.F Yes If user enter 1 character he should move to next edittext